# How to join multiple tables (SQL) to find the difference between an order and shipped quantities?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a collection of orders that were submitted to an internal ERP, which were processed and partially shipped.

The table hierarchy is as follows:

- `Order` table contains `OrderReference(PO), OrderID`
- `OrderItems` table contains `Product/Lot/Qty` requested (`OrderID` is `parentID` that joins these tables)
- `Shipping` contains `OrderReference(PO), ShippingID`
- `ShippingArchive` contains `Product/Lot/Qty` that was shipped (`ShippingID` is parent that joins these tables)

I want to create a report that looks as follows:

```
OrderReference#

Order Requested / Shipped Items / Missing Pieces

PC/Lot/Qty    -   PC/Lot/Qty    - PC/Lot/Qty
```

I have used a temp table to get some of the data but I realize I'm taking the wrong approach. I should be able to do all of this with a single query, though it will seemingly be a bit complex.

I get held up when I try to think about how to join where pieces don't exist, and where to perform the mathematics in my sorting and filtering. Please help!

Sincere thanks :)